# How to make sure the server uses the gateway from eth0 at multiple DHCP network setup

Tags: networking, dhcp, gateway

I run a Ubuntu server in VirtualBox with 3 network interfaces. How can I make sure the default gateway is always the on from eth0.

```
eth0 -> NAT, DHCP
eth1 -> bridged, DHCP
eth2 -> host only adapter, static ip
```

I know how to do it manually...

```
$ sudo route del default
$ sudo route add default gw 10.0.2.2
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The NAT network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The bridged network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# The host-only network interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.56.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

Thanks, Stefan

Comment: You really do not need the `network` and `broadcast` in a `static` setup.  That will be calculated by the OS.  So adding them only makes it possible that you get it wrong, and then your net will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears when `eth1` go up, because also from `dhcp` got `default gw` param. You can add in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` some script to returns default gw to `eth0`

Example:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth1" ] || exit 0
# Return default interface and gw
route add default dev eth0
```

give `script` privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/ppp/if-up.d/script
```

`if-up.d` will trigger script called `script` when `eth1` go `up` and return `default gw` to `eth0`